# Episerver find facets

Tags: c#, search, facet, episerver

I am building an restaurantfinder website with EPiServer and I'm using EPiFind to search on the site. I've encountered a problem though. I'm trying to facet a pagetype in the pagetree, although I'm only searching in one specific pagetype. My goal is to be able to print out the titles of the pagetype. So if I search for example Sweden, all cities that's in the pagetree should be listed with their names in the facet.

My code:

```
if (query == null && tags == null && cities == null)
{
    return View();
}

var q = SearchClient.Instance.Search<RestaurantPage>()
    .For(query)
    .TermsFacetFor(x => x.CityPage.HeadLine);

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cities))
{
    q = q.Filter(x => x.HeadLine.MatchCaseInsensitive(cities));
}
var results = q.Select(x => new SearchHit
{
    Title = x.HeadLine,
    Url = x.LinkURL,
    Tag = x.Tags,
    Adress = x.Adress,
    Latitude = x.Latitude,
    Longitude = x.Longitude,
    Image = x.RestaurantImage
}).GetResult();

ViewBag.Query = query;
ViewBag.Id = results.ProcessingInfo.ServerDuration;
ViewBag.Hits = results.TotalMatching;

var facets = new List<FacetResult>();      
var testFacet = (TermsFacet)results.Facets["CityPage.HeadLine"];
var testLinks = new FacetResult("Cities", testFacet.Terms.Select(x => new FacetLink
{
    Text = x.Term,
    Count = x.Count,       
}));
facets.Add(testLinks);         

ViewBag.Filters = new List<FacetLink>();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tags))
{
    ViewBag.Filters.Add(new FacetLink
    {
        Text = tags,
        Url = Url.QueryBuilder(currentPage.ContentLink).AddSegment("?query=" + query).ToString()
    });
}


return View(new SearchResult(results, query) {Facets = facets});
```

Comment: Are you not getting any facets at all, or not the ones you're expecting?

Comment: @TedNyberg I'm getting some facets, just not the one included in the code above.

Comment: I'd say that the CityPage property (a PageData object?) isn't indexed. My guess is you need to configure your indexing to include that property, or possibly the Headline property explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

In order to retrieve the facets, you could do:

```
results.TermsFacetFor<RestaurantPage>(x => x.CityPage.HeadLine)
```